# Directive inside table is rendered outside table

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive with isolated scope like this:

```
.directive('hello', function() {

    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      template: '<h1>Hello Directive</h1>',
      scope: {}
    };

});
```

If I put that directive inside a table, weirdly enough, the directive is rendered outside the table, even when used as an attribute:

```
<table>    
  <tr>
    <hello></hello>

    <td>Cell 1</td>             
    <td>Cell 2</td>             
    <td>Cell 3</td>             
  </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

Any workarounds?

I created a Codepen to demonstrate this: http://codepen.io/jviotti/pen/AtnzJ/.

**EDIT:** I tried wrapping the `h1` in a `td`. It still renders outside the table:

[image]

Comment: yeah dont create a custom element, use something like `<td hello></td>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's missing a `<td>` tag wrapping the element, an `<h1>` can't be inserted directly as a child of `<tr>`.

Comment: I've wrapped the `h1` in a `td`. The directive still renders outside the table. Test in codepen.

Comment: I guess you've done it inside the directive template. In the render process, the browser first tries to make a valid HTML before angular comes into stage. Another possibility would be using the directive as attribute, or comment, not as element. Check this in case of doubt http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xBLyh/

Answer (score 1):

this layout works for me:

```
<div ng-app="app">
   <table>    
       <tr>
           <td><hello></hello></td>
           <td>Cell 1</td>              
           <td>Cell 2</td>              
           <td>Cell 3</td>              
        </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```